# Convert a string vector to numbers then get sd() of those numbers

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` FINAL where 1 column called *Cluster-sizes* contains a string of numbers like this.

"2,3,4,5"

I'd like to create a new column called ClusterSigma that will convert these to numerical values, then provide the standard deviation of the numbers by row in the `dataframe`.

I'm using this but getting an error..?

```
getnums <- function(x) {sd(as.integer(strsplit(x,",")[[1]]))}
FINAL$ClusterSigma <- apply(FINAL$ClusterSizes,1,getnums)
```

Any ideas..?

Comment: You can probably just do `getnums(FINAL$ClusterSizes)` without the `apply()`

Comment: you cannot use apply on a vector, which is what `FINAL$ClusterSizes` is

Comment: No that produces the sd() of the first row and pastes it down along all rows...I was hoping the apply would apply the effect to each row...ie vectorise it

Comment: Its hard to understand your data without posting it. Please post the results of `dput(FINAL)` or `dput(head(FINAL))`

Comment: but you only have one vector as input, then you split it and compute the sd of the result of the `strsplit` call. I think what you need is a `sapply` : `sapply(FINAL$ClusterSizes, getnums)` to run your function along your vector.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this `rowSds` (from `matrixStats`) after reading the column with `read.csv` to create a `data.frame` and converting it to a `matrix`.

```
library(matrixStats)
rowSds(as.matrix(read.csv(text=as.character(df1$Clustersize), header=FALSE)))
#[1] 1.290994 1.290994
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Clustersize = c("2,3,4,5", "3,4,5,6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since strsplit will output a list, you could try `unlist()`?

```
test1 <- data.frame(Clustersizes=c("2,3,4,5", "1,1,1,1", "1,5,2,6"))
test1$ClusterSigma <- unlist(
  lapply(
    lapply(strsplit(as.character(test1$Clustersizes), ','), as.numeric), 
    sd))
test1
>  Clustersizes ClusterSigma
>1      2,3,4,5     1.290994
>2      1,1,1,1     0.000000
>3      1,5,2,6     2.380476
```